# How to change the TextDecoration.Underline with a custom style?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I wanted to apply **custom underline** style to the underlined text. Can we change within `TextDecoration.underline` ??

```
textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.titleMedium.copy(
    textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
    fontWeight = FontWeight.W600,
    color = color,
    textDecoration = TextDecoration.Underline
)
```

Comment: How do you want to change it?

Comment: Any custom changes like color, width etc.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of using `textDecoration = TextDecoration.Underline` you can simply draw a line at the bottom of the `Text`.

Something like:

```
Text(
    modifier = Modifier.drawBehind {
        val strokeWidthPx = 1.dp.toPx()
        val verticalOffset = size.height - 2.sp.toPx()
        drawLine(
            color = Teal200,
            strokeWidth = strokeWidthPx,
            start = Offset(0f, verticalOffset),
            end = Offset(size.width, verticalOffset)
        )
    },
    text = text,
)
```

[image]

If you have a `Text` with more than 1 line you have to calculate text height and draw the line for each line of text.

Comment: Best answer for custom underline.